# Style of the .net dropdown list - the pop-up list

Tags: css, .net

can anyone advise how to the style of the .net dropdown list - the pop-up list?
For example, I have set outline:none, and get the following result:

[image]

The outline is still there for the dropdown, only the outline of the head is removed. I know how to style each of the listitem, but can anyone advise how to style to dropdown itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can set CSS for that like this:

```
#xyz is your dropdownlist id    

`select#xyz 
{
  border:0px;
  outline:0px;
}`
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Okay so can i see your CSS And HTML code? So maybe i can help you.